# How to access content from Dictionary or Array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

In my app i have some special scenario which i am not able to handle.
I am getting data from Xml which i am putting in two Arrays Label and numProjects.
Label contains labels and numProjects contains values for respective labels.

With these values i need to draw a pie chart with different colors for each label.
The way i am drawing the chart is i put the data with which i need to populate the chart in one array and in other array i put colors which i need for different sections.

So here's the problem with code:

```
labelArray = [Active, pipeline, closed];
numProjectArray = [248, 438,200];// respective values as per the labelArray
```

Now while drawing i need this `numProjectArray` and also i need to create another array which has all the colors i want to color the separate sections. Also there should be a specific pair for each of label-value-color. For each label there should be a unique value which is stored in `numProjectArray` and for this label-value pair we need a specific color to draw the section. And also need to display this information on side of graph that which color denotes which label.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking how to do this better, you should probably be thinking about something like an array of dictionaries, with one dictionary per label/value/color. Each dictionary would have keys like @"label", @"numProjects", and @"color", and corresponding values.

Comment: but what if the number of labels are unknown??

Comment: Just add more dictionaries to the array, one per label. You don't have to use dictionaries here -- you could come up with your own class to store the data -- but NSDictionary provides a simple container for key/value pairs and should work perfectly well. The main thing is that you should keep all information for each label together rather than spreading it across several arrays and trying to keep those arrays in sync.